Discrete family of probability distributions and complete sufficient statistics
I need to figure out atleast two families of discrete probability distributions, one where complete sufficient statistics exist and another where it doesnt. I was able to find Power series family of distribution(psd) and exponential family of distribution( discrete ones) where complete sufficient statistic exist. Please help me in figuring out some other discrete families of distributions to answer the question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
